# How can Bootstrap glyphicons be marked up using Jade?

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, pug

I tried to add glyphicons at my HTML, something important to say is that I'm redering from Jade.

For inside buttons glyphicons I tried:

```
button(ng-click='doLexycalValidation()').btn.btn-default 
    span.glyphicon.glyphicon-search
    | Evalular
```

For glyphicons at tables I tried:

```
tr.table.table-hover
    td
    span.glyphicon.glyphicon-search
    | Evalular
```

But got not result at any of these. I'm importing Bootstrap from CDN this way:

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css')
link(rel="stylesheet",href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css")
```

How can I make them work properly?

Comment: it works for me http://fiddlesalad.com/jade/test-bootstrap-icons

Comment: would be helpful if you tell what is your expected HTML output

Answer (score 0):

You can use this module JADE-Bootstrap
http://rajasegar.github.io/JADE-Bootstrap/index.html

install by => **npm install --save jade-bootstrap**

and use it like this

```
extends ../node_modules/jade-bootstrap/_bootstrap
block body
    button.btn.btn-success(type='submit') 
         +icon("plus") 
        | Add
    +a-btn-danger("#")
        +icon('remove') 
        | Remove
```

this module JADE-Bootstrap is very good.It make jade and bootstrap 3 work together more easy.